# Magento - show Original Price in Cart template

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, cart

Using Catalog Price Rules, I'm trying to show that there was a discount applied to the particular product once viewing the cart page.  Currently, Magento stops showing the "crossed-out" price when viewing the cart, so it doesn't appear that they received a discounted price unless they go back to the product / catalog page.

The area in question is located around line 103:

**template > checkout > cart > item > default.phtml**

What would be the proper way to show the original price next to the current price within this section?  I serioulsly have no idea how it works and can't find anything on the net regarding this, as it's much different setup than anything inside View.phtml

```
<?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Due to the random / low responses I get from alternate StackExchange websites, I've also posted this question here:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42494/show-original-price-in-cart
and will update my question accordingly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `$_item->getProduct()->getPrice()` to get the original price.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getProduct()->getPrice()) ?>
```